# Custom Transformer for raw SQL query using NHibernate

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate

I have a table of `customerorders` that are tied to a table of `purchases`. Every order can have multiple purchases, it's peculiar but imagine it as if you paid for each item separately at checkout. Every order has a customer name and date, every purchase has a payment type and total on them.

I have a nifty query that provided you know the *name* of the customer, you can find their most recent unique purchase types.

For example:
Customer `A` made 3 orders total, 2 via credit card and 1 via cash.

I ask the database "what's the newest unique orders by payment type for `A`?" Database returns 2 results - the most recent credit card order & the 1 cash order.

This is query:

```
String sqlQueryStr = $@"SELECT ee.PaymentType, ee.Total
FROM
(
            SELECT e.CustomerName, ee.PaymentType, ee.Total, MAX(e.Date) as MaxTimestamp
                FROM customerorders ee
                INNER JOIN purchases e ON e.Id=ee.OrderId WHERE CustomerName='{customerName}'
                GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
) AS sub
INNER JOIN purchases e ON e.Date = sub.MaxTimestamp AND e.CustomerName = sub.CustomerName
INNER JOIN customerorders ee ON ee.OrderId=e.Id AND ee.PaymentType = sub.PaymentType;"

ISQLQuery query = session.CreateSQLQuery(sqlQueryStr);
return query.SetResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(typeof(Purchase)))
            .List<Purchase>();
```

This works great on its own. The result would be as follows for Customer A, and I have what I want:

1. 'PaymentType: Credit  Total:100'
2. 'PaymentType: Cash Total:50'

However, now I want to do something where I don't provide 'customerName'. I want to get *everyone's* in the same way.

Now if you recall what I said before, `Purchase` does not have a `CustomerName`. So I can't just remove the `WHERE` and use the transformer anymore!

When I remove the 'WHERE' and add an additional SELECT for `e.CustomerName`, I get this output in MySQL using the query:

1. 'CustomerName: A PaymentType: Credit  Total:100'
2. 'CustomerName: A PaymentType: Cash Total:50'
3. 'CustomerName: B PaymentType: Credit Total:20'
4. 'CustomerName: C PaymentType: Credit Total:15'

I was thinking of making a custom transformer, but I'm not sure what kind of transformer will allow me to process this kind of result. It's now not not just a `Purchase`, it's got the Name also. And I would probably want them grouped together right (not on different rows)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public sealed class CustomTransformer: IResultTransformer
    {
        public IList TransformList(IList collection)
        {
            return collection;
        }

        public object TransformTuple(object[] tuple, string[] aliases)
        {
            return new UniqueCustomerPurchase()
            {
                   CustomerName = (string)tuple[0],
                   PaymentType = (string)tuple[1],
                   Total = (uint)tuple[2]
            };
        }
    }
```

This is what I have at the moment. This seems to work well, however, I wish there was a way to group the CustomerName to a list of Purchases(paymentType & total) instead of having to do this. I end up having to iterate over the collection a second time to group them like so:

```
ISQLQuery query = session.CreateSQLQuery(sqlQueryStr);
return query.SetResultTransformer(new CustomTransformer())
            .List<UniqueCustomerPurchase>()
            .GroupBy(cp => cp.CustomerName)
            .Select(g => new KeyValuePair(g.Key, g.Select(cp => cp));
```